# Woocommerce Product name and quantity on same row

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Need to align woocommerce product name and quantity in same row of checkout review form.

Original PHP code here:

```
<td class="product-name">
    <?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) . '&nbsp;'; ?>
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times;&nbsp;%s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
    <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
</td>
```

Website: n7rent.com

[image: screenshot of UI]

Tried changing the PHP but not working. Hence looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is such that the entire left side with name, quantity and dates is one column and the price on the right is another column. If you want to move the quantity on the right with no strcutural changes you will have to give absolute positioning to the quantity and relative to the immediate parent (name wrapper)

```
.shop_table .product-name{
position:relative;
}
.shop_table .product-quantity{
position: absolute;
top: 36px;
right: -15px;
}
```

You can ofcourse adjust the styling according to your placement needs, do keep in mind to check the responsiveness on different device sizes

[image: screenshot of website with added css]

Comment: Css is works but it has responsive is the issue. So would prefer a hardcode way if possible. Anyway the table can be rearranged?